# Metaspace utilization of JVM

Tags: jvm, heap-memory, jstat

I am facing issue with my application which runs in a docker. Out of blue it crash after 30 minutes. As my application deals which cache so first suspect is the memory utilization . I googled and find out using **jstat -gcutil** command we can monitor heap space utilization .

I ran the command with the start of application and for it showed Metaspace utilization as 98% which is quite odd.

**So my question is , is this utilization showing that my application is using 98% of OS memory for the JVM process or 98% of OS memory is available for JVM ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows the current Metaspace occupancy relative to the current Metaspace capacity, i.e.

```
    used / capacity
```

Metaspace `used`, `capacity`, `committed` and `reserved` values are illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40899996/3448419).

This is a rather useless metrics since Metaspace can grow and shrink during an application lifecycle.