# I get confused with MaxMetaspaceSize

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I launched jvm with JAVA_OPTS like this:

`JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms1500m -Xmx1500m -Xmn455m -XX:MetaspaceSize=128m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m"`

After a time, when I look over GC log：

`[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 352K->0K(460288K)] [ParOldGen: 1069272K->352585K(1070080K)] 1069624K->352585K(1530368K), [Metaspace: 333651K->333631K(1808384K)], 0.5450331 secs] [Times: user=1.46 sys=0.00, real=0.54 secs]`

I'm confused.I have already set MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m, but according to log, there are 1808384K(about 1.7G) actually, why?

Comment: The metaspace used is 333 MB but the maximum is 1800 MB which doesn't appear to make sense unless the option isn't being used although your `-Xmn` and `-Xmx` does appear to be about right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MaxMetaspaceSize` limits the amount of **committed** metaspace memory, while the GC log prints the amount of **reserved** virtual memory. Reserved address space does not necessarily occupy any physical memory or swap space.

[More about Metaspace structure »](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40899996/3448419)